# Regular expression to find group of tags for PHP

Tags: php, regex

Please help me to write regular expression to find group of tags

output

```
[et_pb_...] [tag] [/et_pb_...]
```

(dots any text) if it is inside some other tags like

input

```
[et_pb_row][et_pb_columntype="1_2"]

[et_pb_codeadmin_label="Code"] [tag] [/et_pb_code]

[/et_pb_column]
[/et_pb_row]
```

other input

```
[et_pb_section fullwidth="on" specialty="off"]
[et_pb_fullwidth_code admin_label="Fullwidth Code"]
[tag]
[/et_pb_fullwidth_code]
[/et_pb_section]
```

And only 3 thing same all the time

**[et_pb_**...can be any text here]

**[tag]**

**[/et_pb_**...can be any text here]

I have this

```
[et_pb_section fullwidth="on" specialty="off"]
[et_pb_fullwidth_code admin_label="Fullwidth Code"]
[tag]
[/et_pb_fullwidth_code]
[/et_pb_section]
```

I need to get only this

```
[et_pb_fullwidth_code admin_label="Fullwidth Code"][tag][/et_pb_fullwidth_code]
```

UPDT
I got it to work 
[DEMO](https://eval.in/577858)

Comment: what do you want to find?

Comment: Please post a clear sample of the **input** and desired **output**.

Comment: other tags ……..from here [et_pb_ …….[tag]…….[/et_pb_.....]to here ….other tags

Comment: find this [et_pb_....] [tag] [/et_pb_...]

Comment: Please update you question with that information. Clearly state "**I have this"** and in need **"this"**

Comment: Maybe something [like this](https://eval.in/577716) you want? See [regex here](https://regex101.com/r/aW8nT7/1). But this would not check if inside some other tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something Like:

```
preg_match_all('%(?:\[et_pb_.*?\]){2}\s+(\[et_pb_.*?\] \[tag\] \[/et_pb_.*?\])\s+(\[/et_pb_.*?\])%i', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
echo $result[1][0];
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rB7wK6/1)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, can please make update to search based only on  "[/et_pb_" not on "[/et_pb_code" if it is possible. As I said only this is the same "et_pb_"  tag name can be different ([et_pb_row], [et_pb_code], [et_pb_column])

Comment: It works but i forgot to skip the first capture group `?:` https://eval.in/577748

Comment: Pedro can you please update it one more time for second input eval.in/577752